# Apple script MS Word Page count in folder

Tags: applescript

I am new to this scripting field.
I need to know how to count the pages of a doc file in a folder.
Now I am trying it for MS Word but it's getting a "missing value" error.
Can anyone suggest sg about it?

Below is the script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"

activate
    --Count the pages:
    set allpage_count to length of the front document
    set page to "Pages: " & allpage_count

    --Assemble the text for the dialog box:
    set dialogText to page
    display dialog dialogText
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the pages, use the `get range information` command on a text range, like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    set allpage_count to get range information (character 1 of active document) information type number of pages in document
    display dialog "Pages: " & allpage_count
end tell
```

---

It's possible to count pages in **.docx** without opening "Microsoft Word", but i don't know for **.doc**

```
set thisFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select a folder which contains .docx files"
set r to do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of thisFolder) & "; for tDoc in *.docx;
do
   r=$(unzip -p \"$tDoc\" docProps/app.xml | sed -nE 's:.*<Pages>([0-9]*)</Pages>.*:\\1:p')
   echo \"$tDoc = $r pages\"
done"
tell application "TextEdit" to make new document with properties {text:r}
```

**Important** :

- This script works on document saved by "**Microsoft Office**".

  This script doesn't work on **.docx** file created by another application
  like (**Pages** of Apple", **LibreOffice**), these applications do not put this information in the "`app.xml`" file

Comment: Thanks you its  working.
But now i am trying it do it  without opening the MS word and count page  directly from folder and give output in text edit.
for example

If we have a folder with  A word file = 2 page and B word file = 4 page it should display in text edit with output like this

Total Word file = 2
A word file = 2 page
B word file = 4 page
Total pages = 6 pages.

Now i am working on this Let me know if there is any suggestion for this.

Comment: Thanks jack 
 I have checked the script but is not displaying the count of docx pages in the folder selected in  text edit. it gives the output
Like this
06Gandhi-nzsth-2015-0032 copy 2.docx =  pages
09Gandhi-nzsth-2015-0045 copy 3.docx =  pages

But it displays  =pages not how much total page it contains.
for example 
09Gandhi-nzsth-2015-0045 copy 3.docx =  5pages
09Gandhi-nzsth-2015-0045 copy 3.docx =  5pages
Total 10 pages.

Working on its lets see wat can be done.

Comment: This script works on old docx (2008) and new docx created on Office 2016. See my answer.

Comment: yes jack  it works now.Hope i learn more things from you in upcoming days.
Thank you.